# AppleScript cURL

Tags: curl, applescript

I'm having hard times getting the following script working. So what it's supposed to
do is:
I want to set a timer for the script to safe a jpg version of www.url.com/picture.aspx
on my HDD with a ongoing filename like picture-0001.jpg up to picture-xxxx.jpg.

```
set {tUrl, dFolder} to {"www.url.com/picture.aspx", "~/Desktop/curlDownload/"}

set {oAStid, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "/"}
set fName to (last text item of tUrl) as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oAStid

do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder & "; curl -A/--user-agent " & tUrl & " >> " & (dFolder & fName))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

curl cannot be used to save screenshots of a website. You could install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then install [webkit2png](https://paulhammond.org/webkit2png) with `brew install webkit2png`.

It might be easier to just schedule the script with cron. You could run it every other minute by editing the crontab with `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and adding a line like this:

`*/2 * * * * webkit2png -C -s 1 -W 1000 -H 1000 --clipwidth 1000 --clipheight 1000 http://stackoverflow.com -o ~/Desktop/$(date '+\%y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S').png`

(If I misunderstood the question and you're actually trying to download images, something like `curl -O https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png` would save the file with the same filename to the current directory.)